# code to hide dialog box is not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Following is the method i am using to hide dialog box (using sweete alert), it is working in all browser but not working in IE(EDGE). can anyone help ?

```
function hide_Sweet_Alert(){
     jQuery('.sweet-overlay').css({'display':'none'});
     jQuery('.sweet-alert').css({'display':'none'}).addClass('hideSweetAlert');
}
```

Comment: ie11 or edge? ie11 doesnt use edge,

Answer (score 0):

Use swal.close() to close the sweat alert.

Comment: i tried that but it is not allowing to open other dialog box inside that swal.